# How to Match() a range with multiple criteria AND using a wildcard

Tags: google-sheets

[![I have this spreadsheet:][1]][1]

i need table 2 to display the reasons of absense for every day in between (and including) the start and end date listed in the first table.

the "Dates" column in table 1 contains every date i need to check, so that part is out the way. The formula in column H should display a value if the corrosponding cell in column D contains a match for column G, but i can't figure out how to implement the correct wildcard.

EDIT: [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t_O6MGqVEBy8r_jpAmRgJ6oDoFC-dr5OWHAT6ahIaWA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please provide a sample sheet, so that we can help you without needing to recreate it from an image.

Comment: Added a link to the sheet in the orignal post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula on cell H2 and drag right and down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$E$8,MATCH(1,(H$1=$A$2:$A$8)*($G2>=$B$2:$B$8)*($G2<=$C$2:$C$8),0)),"")
```